# snackbar without content view

Tags: android, android-snackbar

I make a splash screen without any content view (just with logo image as theme background), which shown till app initialization done.

If an error occurs during initialization I'd like to notify user by snackbar. Is there a way to show snackbar without inflating content view?

I tried to pass `getWindow().getDecorView()` as `view` argument to `Snackbar.make()`, but nothing happened.

Comment: `Snackbar` is just an ordinary `View`. Where do you expect it to be laid out in order to be seen? You have to add to your root view, right? You may show `Toast`, which is not added to your view hierarchy.

Comment: Can you show your slash activity code?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should be passing `getWindow().getDecorView().getRootView()`:

```
Snackbar.make(getWindow().getDecorView().getRootView(), "Some error occured", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG).show();
```